# How can I assign a range of cells to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I'm trying to create a simple 1D array using the following code.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim search() As Variant
Dim data() As Variant
Worksheets("IO List").Activate
Set searchitems = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "U1")
Set ExportData = ActiveSheet.Range("A3", "U3")
search = searchitems.Value
MsgBox (search(1))
End Sub
```

The message box is simply to check the value of the array but I am thrown the error: Runtime error '9': Subscript or of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning cell values to an array, you **always** get a 2-D array even if you are only collecting the values from a single column or single row.

Application.transpose will convert row data from a single column into a one-based 1-D array. Using it twice will convert column data from a single row into a one-based 1-D array.

```
Dim search As Variant, data As Variant

Worksheets("IO List").Activate
search  = Application.transpose(Application.transpose(Range("A1", "U1").value))
data = Application.transpose(Application.transpose(Range("A3:U3").value))

MsgBox search(1)
```

Comment: Thank you @jeeped. Worked perfectly

Comment: Using the early-bound `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose` will be about 18% faster, and using `Value2` will also speed things up too, but transposing twice is more expensive than just copying the values from the 2D array into a new 1D array - that's about 63% faster.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is optimized for working with 2D Variant arrays.

You almost always want `Value2` as opposed to `Value`. (see [TEXT vs VALUE vs VALUE2 – Slow TEXT and how to avoid it](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/))

You can also avoid activating the worksheet by using a `With` block:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim search() As Variant
    Dim data() As Variant
    With Worksheets("IO List")
        search = .Range("A1", "U1").Value2
        ExportData = .Range("A3", "U3").Value2
    End With
    MsgBox search(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization help. I've added some changes. However your vb doesn't actually work. Throws blank data in the message box.

Comment: Works for me. Did you notice that I removed the `searchitems` variable and just set the array with `search = .Range("A1", "U1").Value2`?

Comment: I've already got the section working. But I copied/pasted your vb in to see how it went and it wasn't returning any values.

Comment: place a break on the MsgBox statement, and check the Locals Window for the values in `search`. If `search` isn't populated, then you'll need to go back and make sure the assignment to `search` is referring to the correct workbook/sheet/range.